# how to select one image of a object stored in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, top-n

product table in SQL
tables:

```
Product: 
    ID,
    Name

ProductImage
    ID,
    ProductID,
    Image
```

I want to select an image in select query of Product
I need first/last image of product1, first/last image of product2, etc

Something like:

```
select Product.id,Product.name,(select top(1)image from productimage where productimage.ProductID=product.ID)as Image from product
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,Maybe useful:

```
select Product.id,Product.name,
(select top (1) image from productimage where productimage.ProductID=product.ID order by productimage.ID asc)as FirstImage ,
(select top (1) image from productimage where productimage.ProductID=product.ID order by productimage.ID desc) as LastImage
from product
```

Answer (score 0):

Temp Table subqueries are better for long run over column level subqueries.

Ex:

```
SELECT
    Product.id,
    Product.name,
    productImageTable.Image AS Image 
FROM Product INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    ProductID,
    Min(image) as Image 
FROM productimage 
GROUP BY ProductID) AS productImageTable ON 
    productImageTable.ProductID=Product.ID
```